# Model-View-Controller: who creates whom?

Tags: design-patterns, mvc, architectural-patterns

In "Pattern Oriented Software Architecture - Vol 1" (p. 131), the author said that `View` is responsible for creating `Controller`. But in "Head First Design Patterns" (p. 562) it is the `Controller` that creates the `View`. In some other references I see that nor `View` niether `Controller` create each other. Only `Controller` has a reference of `View` and/or vice versa.
What's your opinion about this? Does this depend?

Comment: I don't think MVC specifies this so it probably depends on the implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I can only assume this changes along different platforms.
On the android library, you create the view from the controller.

i.e., in your `Activity` you call `setContentView...` to "awake" you XML (The view) and create it.

On the other hand, in the iOS world, you would ask the View (`storyboard` or `.xib` file) to awake (Actually you ask the system to go to the app's bundle, get the View and create it) itself up, than it will awake your controller (e.g., `myView`) and `awakeFromNib` will be called...

I might not be precise about the small details, but you can see that different platforms would create this connection in slightly different ways, depends on the architecture.

Answer (score -1):

Does it really matter what creates what though? It depends imo, as long as business logic and view are separated it's alright. Controller should have a reference to both of them and provide means to translate data from the logic to the view and vice versa. But honestly, in real world applications, no matter how hard you try you will put some of the logic inside of the controller too.

Comment: It depends how you define `logic`. If, for instance, the user clicks on `Login` button, than I would assume the minimum the Controller can do is 1) Get the click action, 2) Call the responsible model function with `user name` and `password` 3) Wait for the success/fail and present it to the user. BUT - If the controller need to simply check if both texts (`user` and `pass`) are not empty - I wouldn't say this is logic in the Controller. Making a regex validation on the strings on the other hand, is logic that should go somewhere else and give answer to the Controller...